# ubuntu server 20.04.2 terminal how to scroll up?

Tags: ubuntu, server, terminal, scroll

hi first thank you for reading my question.

I want to scroll up to see the previous lines at terminal in ubuntu server 20.04.2(this is installed on virtual box).
"ctrl + alt + up/down", "shift + page up/down". already i did but it didn't work.

someone could you help me?
really i will thank you for your awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

i couldn't find why it didn't work but found a trick to solve the problem.

when use virtual box on window mode and make the window size more smaller than real size, the window have a scroll that can scroll up.

this is a temporary way and useful.